# Recycleview show only one item

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I set the height as wrap content, and the row still take the whole page
what should I do to fix this problem?

this is the xml file of the row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pink"
        android:text="c'est quel module"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/msg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="15:12"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

update this is the java code of the mainActivity class !

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Message> mList;
    RecycleAdapter recycleAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mList=new ArrayList<>();

        mList.add(new Message("Hello Trippin","12:00"));
        mList.add(new Message("Whats good","15:02"));

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycleAdapter=new RecycleAdapter(mList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Java Code

Comment: @Hossame Makhlof Please provide your adapter and activity code where the recyclerview is initialized

Comment: By the way you should use the `LinearLayout` as the root element and remove the useless `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I dont think it should take whole screen. Check your recyclerview

Comment: remove android:background="@drawable/background" of relative layout and check

Comment: Change parent layout (RelativeLayout) to something else

Answer (score 0):

you are using horizontal orientation, this is default. and you used "match_parent" width for this reason you see only one item.

add vertical orientation your linearlayout

> ```
>    android:orientation="vertical"
> ```

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of your drawable files:

`@drawable/background` and `@drawable/pink`

Please check their height and make changes accordingly so that row item gets displayed according to your needs.